# Simplifying Angular 2 barrels

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a folder with many services and models that are used (imported) all over the application - in my case these are clients for an API and models for data.

I'm looking to simplify imports for the calling code, so I'm looking into creating a [barrel](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/glossary.html#B). I also would want to provide constants similar to Angular's `HTTP_PROVIDERS` to make it easier to register the exported services with Angular.

My approach currently is:

1. Import the symbol from its file
2. Re-export it, so it can be imported individually
3. Add it to the an appropriate array constant, e.g. `API_SERVICES`, so it can be registered with Angular

This results in three lines of code for each exported symbol. This seems overly verbose and I'm worried the lists will go out of sync.

```
import { LanguageApi } from "./language-api.service";
export { /*... ,*/ LanguageApi /*, ...*/ };
export const API_SERVICES: any[] = [ /*... ,*/ LanguageApi /*, ...*/ ];
```

I'd like to make it more DRY. Is there any way to make it shorter? Perhaps I could somehow reuse the `API_SERVICES` array to export its contents as individual symbols?

Comment: I guess, that's how you do it ... https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/http/http.ts

Comment: @rinukkusu The link of yours is broken.

Comment: @DonkeyBanana well, things have changed a little in the last 2 years :)

Answer (score 0):

You could separate create a barrel with exports only and make another file for constants... For example

```
// index.ts
export { LanguageApi } from "./language-api.service";
export * from "./some-other.service";

// providers.ts
import { LanguageApi } from "./index";
export const API_SERVICES: any[] = [ /*... ,*/ LanguageApi /*, ...*/ ];
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This only splits up the same amount of code between two files, which may be arguably better, depending on how you look at it. However, what I'm looking for is a way to not list each service twice - both in the array and in the `export`. Ideally, somehow use the contents of the `API_SERVICES` array in the export.

Comment: I know it's not much of an improvement, but it's a bit easier to import from the bundle then from individual files. I'm not aware of any way to export array of modules.. they are still new in js/ts world (: